# Controller not getting loaded with custom tile

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have made a custom tile with sap ui5 using generic tiles.Now i'm using it as my custom tile in fiori launchpad.So,when the application loads , it loads the xml view for the tile but gives 404 error for the tile's controller.

```
    The view instantiation resulted in js errorError: failed to load 
    'tile2/viewTile/controller/View1.controller.js' from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.64.0/resources/tile2/viewTile/controller/View1.controller.js: 404
```

Though the xml view is getting loaded also the namespace and everything else is getting configured automatically

```
Name:
viewtile.view.View1
Prefix:
viewtile
Path:
/sap/fiori/viewtile/
```

Getting this

[image]

Actual result should be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration and paths.
The error message says: 
“… failed to load … from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.64.0/resources/tile2/viewTile/controller/View1.controller.js: 404”

You won’t find your own developed View1.controller.js on https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.64.0 .
A similar problem was discussed here: https://answers.sap.com/questions/98633/fiori-launchpad-custom-tile-controllerjs-path-issu.html
The answer was to remove the application name from the view and controller files when deploying to the Fiori Launchpad.